# Is it possible to query table storage from .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm attempting to query table cache using LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<DocumentMetaDataEntity> Get(string connectionString, string cacheName, DeconstructedFileName deconstructedFileName, FileMetaDataFilters filters)
{
    var acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(cacheName);
    var translations = from entity in table.CreateQuery<DocumentMetaDataEntity>()
                       where (entity.sourceParty == sourceParty.ToLowerTrim()
                                   && entity.destinationParty == destinationParty.ToLowerTrim())
                             || (entity.sourceParty == "YES"
                                   && entity.destinationParty == destinationParty.ToLowerTrim())
                       select entity;

    return translations.Where(x => x.expireAt > DateTime.Now)
                       .Where(x => x.effectiveAt < DateTime.Now);
}
```

However, getting this exception:

> 'CloudTable' does not contain a definition for 'CreateQuery' and no accessible extension method 'CreateQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to query table cache from .net core?**

[image]

For some additinal info, here are the *create* methods available on this class:

[image]

Here are all the dependencies:

[image]

I've removed LINQ from the equation, yet still getting the following issue:

[image]

And the full source is below:

```
public static IEnumerable<DocumentMetaDataEntity> Get(string connectionString, string cacheName, DeconstructedFileName deconstructedFileName, FileMetaDataFilters filters)
{
    var acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(cacheName);
    var query = new TableQuery<DocumentMetaDataEntity>().Where
        (TableQuery.CombineFilters
            (TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("FacilityCode", QueryComparisons.Equal, deconstructedFileName.FacilityCode)
               , TableOperators.And
               , TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("LastName", QueryComparisons.LessThan, deconstructedFileName.LastName)
            )
        );            

    var entities = table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What SDK are you using here? Where is "CloudStorageAccount"?  The error is saying you are trying to call a method that doesn't have a matching signature.  Probably you need to pass some arguments or maybe the method you want to call is not public

Comment: @jcharlesworthuk i've updated, please let me know if the screenshots answer your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently .net core doesn't support querying using Linq as far as I know.
But I know You can do it this

```
var table = acc.GetTableReference("TableName");

var partitionKey = "PartitionKey";

TableQuery<TableModel> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<TableModel>()
      .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey.ToString()));

var entities = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).ToList();
```

EDIT: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367)

EDIT 2: ExecuteQuery extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(this CloudTable table, TableQuery<T> query) where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();

        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        do
        {
            // Retrieve a segment (up to 1,000 entities).
            TableQuerySegment<T> tableQueryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken).Result;

            result.AddRange(tableQueryResult.Results);

            continuationToken = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;
        } while (continuationToken != null);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Here is documentation about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet

Comment: example: // Create the table query.
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"),
        TableOperators.And,
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, "E")));

Comment: what does this mean? `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, "E")`

Comment: in the example you showed me, there are 2 conditions, what happens when you add a third? can you show an example of a third condition added?]

Comment: i've attempted your suggested solution, please view the update to the question, still having the same issue

Comment: this queries that gets generated are plain strings, and that method Combine is just joining those with 'and' or 'or', so if you want to check how to join them I suggest to store this generated query to string variable and take a look how it looks and try to modify it to get what you want

Comment: and TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, "E") is just similar to x => xRowKey.First() < 'E'

Comment: makes sense! unfortunately `ExecuteQuery` does not exist on that class

Comment: wow, by bad. I was answering based on my project code that I didn't wrote... looks like I have extension method defined: https://pastebin.com/J2fuK41D

Comment: Is this still not supported? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/writing-linq-queries-against-the-table-service